# Looking up for a certain file in Linux and print its creation and modification time

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to find some file(s) in a Linux directory based on a certain text that it/they have. Once I figured out the file(s) I want to print the creation and modification time.

For example, I have a directory X that has four files, namely: x1.txt, x2.txt, x3.text, and x4.txt with the following info.

```
x1.txt

Name: Mark
Age: 22
Country: USA

x2.txt

Name: Jiff
Age: 26
Country: USA

x3.txt

Name: Sarah
Age: 30
Country: Canada

x4.txt

Name: Heather
Age: 23
Country: USA
```

What I want is print the creation and modification time of the file(s) that contain(s) "Country: Canada" text

What i have done is I just figured out the files in this format

```
# echo $(grep -rn 'Country: Canada' *)
```

And I got

```
x3.txt:3:Country: Canada
```

I need to firstly extract the file name(s), then use the name(s) as input for a time command to get the creation and modification time.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-l` option for grep to only list the file names:

```
grep -lrn 'Country: Canada' *
```

To print the create/mod time of a file, use `stat`:

```
stat <file>
```

You can format the output how you like:

```
stat --printf "Created: %w\nModified: %y\n"
```

Putting it all together, you can send the output list of the grep to the input list of stat via the `xargs` command:

```
grep -lrn 'Country: Canada' * | xargs stat --printf "Created: %w\nModified: %y\n"
```

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. I am getting the "Created" field is empty. How this can be resolved? Also, How can I print the file name as well using the printf command?

Comment: Run `man stat` to see the docs for the stat command. There are other placeholders that you can use for file name or other timestamps.

Comment: Many Linux/DOS like OS's don't store the creation date. Read your `ls` manual carefully. Good luck.